# WEB API Create sample method with complex parameter "jobject"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create a sample for a call

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JObject value)
```

following the example described here [ASP.NET Web API Help Page Part 2: Providing custom samples on the Help Page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yaohuang1/2012/10/13/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-2-providing-custom-samples-on-the-help-page/)
I setup the file "HelpPageConfig.cs"

```
config.SetSampleResponse("test",
                         new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"), 
                         "Eventos",
                         "Post", 
                         "value");
```

my control is named "EventosController.cs", only when accessing the page in sample shows "not available sample"

the sample I want to show looks like:

```
{
 "field1":"value1",
 "field2":"value2",
 "field3":"value3",
 "field4":"value4",
 "field5":"value5",
 "field6":"value6",
 "field7":"value7",
}
```

what remains to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are showing the sample **response**, not **request**. For a complete help page you might want to add a sample request (for this controller and action or if you plan to use the same sample for type - then for type)

Something like this in your HelpPageConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var requestSample = @"{
field1: 'value1',
field2: 'value2'
}";

    //if there would be just 1 sample for all JObject types:
    config.SetSampleForType(
        requestSample,
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"),
        typeof(JObject));

    //if you want to write the specific sample for each method/media type
    config.SetSampleRequest(requestSample, 
                            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"), 
                            "Eventos", 
                            "Post");
    config.SetSampleRequest(requestSample, 
                            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), 
                            "Eventos", 
                            "Post");
    config.SetSampleRequest(requestSample, 
                            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"), 
                            "Eventos", 
                            "Post");

    //and finally, response sample
    var responseSample = "my response sample response";
    config.SetSampleResponse(responseSample, 
                             new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), 
                             "Eventos", 
                             "Post", 
                             "value");
}
```